# Is there a name for the integral $\int_1^\infty e^{-a(x+\frac{b}{x})}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

It is known that the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-a(x+\frac{b}{x})}dx$ where $a$ and $b$ are two constants is BesselK-like function.

Is there a name for the integral $\int_1^\infty e^{-a(x+\frac{b}{x})}dx$ ?

Comment: Note: $\int_1^\infty f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) dx - \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Comment: This integral corresponds to the incomplete Bessel function  or "leaky aquifer function" $K_{-1}(a,ab)$ as defined by [Harris](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf). You can find details of the properties of this function in many papers by Harris, Fripiat and Jones (with a slightly different definition in the latter case).

Comment: @PaulEnta - You should post your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral corresponds to the incomplete Bessel function or *leaky aquifer function* $K_{-1}(a,ab)$ as defined by [Harris](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf):
\begin{equation}
 K_\nu(x,y)=\int_1^\infty e^{-xt-\frac{y}{t}}\,\frac{dt}{t^{\nu+1}}
\end{equation} 
Hydologist showed that ``water levels in pumped aquifer systems with finite transmissivity and leakage could be analyzed in terms of'' this integral.
You can find many properties of this function, as well as numerical methods to compute it in different regions in the $(a,b)$-plane, in papers by Harris and Fripiat. [Jones](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf) uses a different (but related) definition:
\begin{equation}
 K_\nu(z,w)=\int_w^\infty e^{-z\cosh t}\cosh \nu t\,dt
\end{equation} 
and offers a detailed analysis of its asymptotic expansion for complex values of the parameters.

Comment: You've saved my life Paul Enta :)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy!